# Powershell script for monitoring a list of files in parallel

Tags: powershell, foreach, scheduled-tasks

We have about a half dozen servers that ftp a pair of text file with a status update every five minutes.  We're trying to use a combination of Windows Task Scheduler and a Powershell script as the monitor and alert engine.  The script is looking for files that have not been refreshed in the last 60 minutes and reading the files for any condition other than 'OK'.  We'd like the scheduled task to run every five minutes.

When one of the while conditions are true for a file defined in $statusfiles (see script below) the script is getting hung up looping the same file while it waits for the condition to be false rather than processing the next file in the list and watching the problem files in the background.  We want to know as soon as the script is run if there's a problem reported by any of the status files.

In my first version I used an If-ElseIf-Else approach.  This gave me the immediate notification I was looking for but if I don't loop the alert conditions I don't know how to set a retry interval ($retryinterval) to give us a grace period to fix the underlying problem.

Is it possible to make the foreach method run in parallel against all the files defined in $statusfiles?  Would this be system intensive?  Or is there another approach I'm not seeing?

Thanks in advance for the help!

```
$erroractionpreference="SilentlyContinue"

$filepath = "\\Server\DirectoryA\DirectoryB\DirectoryC"
$statusfiles = "$filepath\opmessage21.txt","$filepath\pgmessage21.txt","$filepath\opmessage23.txt","$filepath\pgmessage23.txt","$filepath\opmessage24.txt","$filepath\pgmessage24.txt","$filepath\opmessage25.txt","$filepath\pgmessage25.txt","$filepath\opmessage26.txt","$filepath\pgmessage26.txt"
$agelimit = "60"
$retryinterval = "1800"
$to = "recipient1@email.com","recipient2@email.com","recipient3@email.com","recipient4@email.com"
$from = "alert@email.com"
$smtp = "smtp.server.com"
$port = "25"

function send-email
{
    Send-MailMessage -Body "$body" -to $to -from $from -Subject "$subject" -smtp $smtp
}

foreach ($statusfile in $statusfiles) {

    # Initialize the filestale and file error variables and strip the path and extension from $statusfile
    $filestale = 0
    $fileerror = 0
    $messageid = $statusfile.split('\.')[-2]

    # Get LastWriteTime of the file and alert the admin if LastWriteTime is older than X minutes
    $lastupdated = (get-childitem $statusfile).LastWriteTime

    while ($lastupdated -lt (get-date).AddMinutes(-$agelimit)) {
        $filestale = 1
        write-host "$messageid is older than $agelimit minutes. (Last updated: $lastupdated)"
        $subject = "$messageid is older than $agelimit minutes"
        $body = "Last updated: $lastupdated"
        send-email
        start-sleep -s $retryinterval
        $lastupdated = (get-childitem $statusfile).LastWriteTime
    }

    # Alert the admin the file is no longer outdated
    if ($filestale = 1) {
        $filestale = 0
        write-host "$messageid has been refreshed. (Last updated: $lastupdated)"
        $subject = "$messageid has been refreshed"
        $body = "Last updated: $lastupdated"
        send-email
    }

    # Check the file for an error and alert the admin if the status is not OK
    $messagecontents = Get-Content -Path "$statusfile" -Raw

    while ($messagecontents -ne 'OK') {
        $fileerror = 1
        write-host "$messageid reported the following error: $messagecontents (Last updated: $lastupdated)"
        $subject = "Error reported by $messageid"
        $body = "$messagecontents (Last updated: $lastupdated)"
        send-email
        start-sleep -s $retryinterval
        $messagecontents = Get-Content -Path "$statusfile" -Raw
        $lastupdated = (get-childitem $statusfile).LastWriteTime
        }

    # Alert the admin the status is now OK
    if ($fileerror = 1) {
        $fileerror = 0
        write-host "$messageid indicates status OK. (Last updated: $lastupdated)"
        $subject = "$messageid indicates status OK"
        $body = "Last updated: $lastupdated"
        send-email
    }

}
```

Comment: have your tried foreach -parallel with a workflow?